# Trying to refer to already existing records in an object and adding it in the database in EF core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Say we have a **Car** entity that has a one to many relationship with a **Driver** entity
I create records of drivers in the database first, then I try to add them to the **car** by referring to their Ids registered in the database.

```csharp
Car {
    // other properties
    public ICollection<Driver> Drivers {get; set;}
}
```

---

to achieve this with EF core I used the straightforward following lines of code

```csharp
   await _context.AddAsync(carInstance) //the carInstance is passed with multiple drivers
```

If a driver doesn't already exist in the databases it's created,
If a driver already exists, an error of duplicate keys occurs

How can I refer to the already existing records of the drivers without occurrence of that error ?

Comment: This question has been asked many times in many forms. The answer is always: attach first what you don't want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the existing records of drivers you need attach them before add them with
**carInstance**

```
_context.AttachRange(exisitngDrivers);
await _context.AddAsync(carInstance)
```